# I am using fpdf. to display the only one username pdf file from mysql database

Tags: fpdf

This code working fine. A PDF is also generated, but one problem is that it displays all the values from the table. But I want to display only single candidate's details.

```
<?php
require("£pdf.php");
mysql_connect('localhost:3306', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('login');
$pdf = new FPDF();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 14);
$pdf->Cell(40, 30, "");
$pdf->AddPage();
$query = mysql_query("select username from login");
while($query_run = mysql_fetch_array($query)){
    $pdf->write(5, $query->run['username']);
}
$pdf->output();
?>
```

Comment: which user u want to see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, your MySQL query asks the database for every username in the table and with the `while()` loop you tell the script to output them as well.

Add a `WHERE` clause to your query to filter the data. 
For example `SELECT username FROM login WHERE id = 1`. This will select the user with the id you've provided, assuming you have a column storing user id's.

You can also use `LIMIT` clause to limit the amount of rows returned. 
Example - `SELECT username FROM login ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1` will select the last username added to the table when sorted by id in descending order. (Once again, assuming you have a column storing the user id's).

You should really look into some MySQL tutorials - [here's](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/) one that popped up on google.

Comment: Sorry, I did not understand your previous comment, there is a link to a mysql tutorial in my post.
Also, I don't think that comments is the best way to ask another question, you might want to search the site if your question hasn't been answered already. If no, make a new one and I'm sure the community will be glad to help! :)

Comment: could you tell me the code how to user image insert in pdf from the database.